# Background image keeps going outside the div?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've done two columns left side to be for text and right side to have a background image. But the background image goes outside the div which creates a scroll! How do I keep it inside the div?

```
Position: relative
Background-image: url('images/flowers.jpg')
Background-repeat: no repeat
Background-size: cover;
Padding: 200px 0
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. You haven't provided enough code to reproduce the problem. (You should also read the formatting help for the Stackoverflow question box so you can present the code in a readable format and supply a live demo).

Comment: Note that CSS is normally written in lower-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error   (no repeat instead of no-repeat, so the css fail for this element)

```
Position: relative
Background-image: url('images/flowers.jpg')
Background-repeat: no-repeat;  
Background-size: cover;
Padding: 200px 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see an error on your css and that is

```
Background-repeat: no repeat;
```

Please make a little fix there.

```
Background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

And please provide your html structure too.